# ZipArchive vs GZipStream

Tags: c#, gzipstream, c#-ziparchive

When we create a ZipArchive from a memory stream we can check the result for number of entries.
Can we do the same for a GZipStream, to know the number of entries ?

For example:

```
using var extractArchive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false);
int i = extractArchive.Entries;
```

is there an equivalent for a Gzip Stream

```
           var ms = new MemoryStream();

        
        using (var gzstream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        {
            gzstream.CopyTo(ms);
        }
```

`ms.Entries`? is this possible is there a way to know the number of files (entries) in a GZip Stream? Can we make a archive from a GZip stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GZipStream` class is for data compression only. It is not an archive format where you have files and directories. It is only a sequence of bytes (a [Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-7.0)), so there are no "entries" to read.